# OS Error: No address associated with hostname, errno = 7 in code, Postman works

Tags: flutter, dart, dio

```
class MarvelRepository {
  Future<CharactersModel> fetchCharacters() async {
    var dio = Dio();
    var timestamp = DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch.toString();
    var publicKey = dotenv.get("MARVELPUBLICKEY");
    var privateKey = dotenv.get("MARVELAPIKEY");
    var hash = _generateMD5(timestamp + privateKey + publicKey);
    var query = "ts=$timestamp&apikey=$publicKey&hash=$hash";
    var res = await dio.get("https://gateway.marvel.com/v1/public/characters?$query");
    var charactersModel = CharactersModel.fromJson(res.data);
    return charactersModel;
  }

  _generateMD5(String data) {
    var content = const Utf8Encoder().convert(data);
    var md5 = crypto.md5;
    var digest = md5.convert(content);

    return hex.encode(digest.bytes);
  }
}
```

[image]

How can Postman successfully get the same address as I do in code, but when I run it I get thrown "OS Error: No address associated with hostname, errno = 7"?

Also, I'm absolutely sure that keys and keys' sequence are fine.

I should also say that `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>` is included. I'm running this on my phone, connected to a WiFi which has internet access

**SOLUTION:** As it came to my knowledge, this is a Flutter 3.13.0 bug which is in investigation. It can be solved by unchecking uncaught exceptions inside the IDE.

Answer (score 0):

**Updated**: 3 line changes. I replaced the `http` package with the `dio`.

Try this:

```
import "dart:convert";
import "dart:developer";

import "package:crypto/crypto.dart";
import "package:dio/dio.dart";
import "package:flutter/material.dart";

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(home: HomeScreen());
  }
}

class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomeScreen({super.key});

  @override
  State<HomeScreen> createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: fetchCharacters,
          child: const Text("Fetch Characters"),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Future<void> fetchCharacters() async {
    final int ts = DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch;
    const String pubKey = "6b557766b545468877af14c771e3aae7";
    const String priKey = "a52f243d7ef6c09f9a52405e0888f09c31f498b6";
    const String apiURL = "http://gateway.marvel.com/v1/public/comics";
    final String hash = generateMd5(ts.toString() + priKey + pubKey);
    final Response<dynamic> response = await Dio().get(
      apiURL,
      queryParameters: <String, dynamic>{
        "ts": ts,
        "apikey": pubKey,
        "hash": hash,
      },
    );
    log(response.data.toString());
    return Future<void>.value();
  }

  String generateMd5(String input) {
    final List<int> encodedIntList = utf8.encode(input);
    final Digest digest = md5.convert(encodedIntList);
    final String returnValue = digest.toString();
    return returnValue;
  }
}
```

Output: https://www.jsonkeeper.com/b/VWKC

Comment: It didn't work either, maybe it's the dio lib?

Comment: No, it's not a library issue. I used the HTTP library. I know the Dio library as well. If you want this solution with the Dio library, I can help with that.

Comment: That code is working as expected. You can copy & paste the whole code into the main.dart file.

Comment: sure, with the dio library would be great. Instead of straight copying and pasting your code I tried to adapt what you gave me into my own structure and code, but it had no useful effect, I really dont know why.